# Installation freezes while installing Ubuntu, POP, Xubuntu, Lubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-installation, freeze

I have an X540Up Asus laptop with AMD R5 M420, an Intel i7-7th Gen CPU, and 8 GB RAM. I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive.

The system takes a long time during the transition between interfaces before installation. When the installation started I waited about two hours but it keeps freezing, so I turn off the laptop by pressing the power button.

I tried Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but encounter the same problem.

I also tried POP OS, Xubuntu OS, and Lubuntu OS, but all have the same problem.

I tried turning the secure boot on and off, but nothing changed.

Do I need to change anything from the BIOS?
I tried a lot, but I didn't get anything.

What is the solution to this problem?

---

1. I downloaded Ubuntu from "https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop".
2. I used rufus to burn it on the flash drive.
3. After selecting the keyboard layout and pressing "Continue".
4. I choose "Normal installation".
5. After that I choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".
6. Choose my time zone.
7. I create my account.
8. When the installer freezes without any error in the log.

Comment: It's unclear exactly where in the installation process the system appears to freeze. It would be helpful if your question could be made specifically about the installation of a singular OS, like the most recent Ubuntu LTS system, for example, and if the problem could include information about what exactly you do during the installation and where it stops and whether there are any log messages in the installation log at that point.

Comment: Try with different USB stick

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed @RomeoNinov

Comment: Try to run memory check https://www.memtest86.com/ ANd also you can run some disk check.

Comment: I changed my hard disk and bought an SSD hard disk 
I will try to check My mmemory @RomeoNinov

Comment: And update the firmware (UEFI or BIOS) before anything else. And if UEFI (i.e, any computer 10 years old or less) make sure you're booting (and consequently installing) in UEFI mode. Try safe graphics mode from the initial Grub menu as well.

Comment: Only use 20.04, not older versions as software must be newer than your hardware. May be similar issues? Asus x541ua Update of UEFI & SSD firmware solved issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414431 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420860